# how to set AppBarButton Icon using svg file resource in UWP/C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Microsoft documentation states that you can set icons using SVG vector graphics files:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/icons

However, when I try to use an svg file to set the icon, it just shows blank:

```
<AppBarButton Label="BitmapIcon">
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Svg/MyButton.svg"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

This is how I added Svg file to my project: Under project I created a Directory "Svg", and inside of Svg folder I added the file "MyButton.svg".  Property of this svg resource file are set to:

BuildAction: content

Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

Custom Tool:

Custom Tool Namespace:

Answer (score 4):

You can not use the .svg file as your `AppBarButton` Icon directly. To load the SVG icon file into an AppBarButton.Icon, you can convert it to a PNG, font, or path, then use [FontIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon), [BitmapIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.bitmapicon) and [PathIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pathicon) to display it. More details, you can look into this similar thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d32a8b5-a4e1-472b-acce-85c92380b799/uwp-how-to-load-svg-icon-into-appbarbuttonicon?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: Thanks.  Incidentally, What pixel dimensions for png file is needed for appbarbutton and navigationviewitem.icon when converting such file?

Comment: @BillMoore The icon pixel more depend on your app design. But the default font size for an AppBarButton Icon is 20px.

Comment:  Linking to the platform issue/request tracking for making these scenarios easier: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1494

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the main problem with converting an SVG file into an PathIcon, is that a PathIcon is specified in XAML as a single "Path" XAML statement. So each Path in the SVG file would need to be smashed into the same "path" statement to be compatible with the single path XAML format for specifying a PathIcon.  This is more inline with the way font's are specified.

However, with that said, SVG is easily translatable or convertible into XAML since its specified in an XML format:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Canvas 
           x:Key="appbar_icon1" 
           Width="76" Height="76" 
           ...>
        <Path ... />
        <Path ... />
        <Path ... />
        ...
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Three methods to get derive this XAML PATH Data from SVG file.

**Method 1: Inkscape**

1) Open or Create your SVG in Inkscape

2) File -> Save As…

3) In the file types, select Microsoft XAML (near the bottom)

4) In the window you have the option of Silverlight compatible. I’d select as it generates cleaner XML

**Method 2: XPS format**

1) Print your SVG to the XPS printer

2) The XPS printer will ask you for a file name. Save it somewhere

3) Rename the file extension to .ZIP

4) Extract all the files in the zips. It will create a bunch of files and folders

5) Hunt down the file. It’s likely under Documents > 1 > Pages > 1.fpage

**Method 3: Cut and Paste SVG file XML**

An SVG is an XML file format. You can open it in your favourite text editor. If you were to open the file and scroll down, checkout the content below.

1) Open SVG File in editor:

```
<g
       transform="translate(0,0)"
       id="layer1">
    <path
        id="path3388"
        d="m 15.6,5 c 0,40 0,40 0,40"
        .../>
    <path
        id="path3390"
        d="m 35,5 c 0,40 0,40 0,40"
        .../>
    ...
</g>
```

2) Manually convert XML Path Tags into XAML path tags:

XAML:

```
<Path Data="F1 m 15.6,5 c 0,40 0,40 0,40" 
      Stroke="Black" 
      StrokeThickness="1" />
<Path Data="F1 m 35,5 c 0,40 0,40 0,40" 
      Stroke="Black" 
      StrokeThickness="1" />
...
```

Comment: There is no need to export into a file to access and copy the SVG data. [You just have to open Inkscape XML editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCALs.png) from Inkscape toolbar. As you select the nodes in the tree, they are also selected in the designer area and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a vectorize icon for an AppBarButton or Navigationviewitem.Icon, and the standard icons provided by Microsoft are not enough, then the best way to find an Icon is to find a free "Icon font" online and load it into your application as a resource, then use FontIcon to set the Icon. (See, https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/free-icon-fonts).

Another alternative is to create your own font and use font creation software such as "FontBird" (https://birdfont.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can always put **content** on your **AppBarButton** element. So, use **Image** and **SvgImageSource** to put as icon on the **AppBarButton** content. Here I have used **16p x 16px** SVG image.

**Original SVG:**

[image]

**AppBarButton with Label:**

[image]

And here is the rest of code

```
this.MyAppBarButton.Content = new Image()
        {
            Source = new SvgImageSource()
            {
                UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/logo.svg")
            }
        };
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me