# What are the exact pixel dimensions for "UWP;'s NavigationView Icon" to avoid pixilation?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

What are the exact pixel dimensions for "UWP's NavigationView Icon" to avoid pixelation?

I'm types to make some custom bitmap images for the icons, and need to set the size of the canvas in the drawing program.

```
<Navigationviewitem.Icon>
    <BitmapIcon UriSource="MyImage.png"/>  
</Navigationviewitem.Icon>
```

What's the exact pixel size of `MyImage.png` to avoid pixelation?

Comment: Given UWP apps are DPI aware, you're better off using SVG's/font glyphs / paths for this

Comment: I wanted to use svg file, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458126/how-to-set-appbarbutton-icon-using-svg-file-resource-in-uwp-c. So far answers received on that question converted me back to bitmaps.

Comment: Pixelation is a problem unique to bitmaps, you should not be able to void that. What you can do is as far as possible to make it more smoothly. For example, make a bigger pixel dimension. Also the effects are influenced by the device resolution.